# GraphQL Lighthouse polices user->can('view') not working

Tags: laravel, graphql, authorization

GraphQL Lighthouse polices `user->can('view')` not working, I have created policy and registered as well in AuthServiceProvider

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model\Post' => 'App\Policies\MyPostPolicy',

];
```

But I am not able to access this condition

```
($user->can('update', $post)) {
    //user is authorized now
}
```

the above can is not working in laravel 6, please address me if I have to add any additional step, please thanks

Comment: "not working": what is not working? What is inside the MyPostPolicy file? At least show it's `update` function so we can see what's happening there. Also make sure that code is really accessed, add a dump call to check.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my config/ligthouse.php file's middleware like this in order to make it work:

```
   'middleware' => [            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
\Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Http\Middleware\AcceptJson::class,
\Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Http\Middleware\AttemptAuthentication::class
],
```